# Cannot login to cyradm to administrate Cyrus IMAP

Tags: centos5, imap, cyrus

I have a fresh installation of cyrus-imapd (2.3) on CentOS 5 with all these packages:

- cyrus-imapd
- cyrus-imapd-utils
- cyrus-sasl
- cyrus-sasl-plain
- cyrus-sasl-md5

I have changed the password of user cyrus: `passwd cyrus`.

I am trying to log in to cyradm with `cyradm -user cyrus localhost`, but, when I enter my password, I get the following error message:

```
Login failed: generic failure at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/Cyrus/IMAP/Admin.pm
```

I am afraid that I have the same problema that is explained in [cyradm: cannot authenticate to server](http://lists.andrew.cmu.edu/pipermail/info-cyrus/2008-April/028846.html), but I am not able to solve it with the [hints given by that guy](http://lists.andrew.cmu.edu/pipermail/info-cyrus/2008-April/028847.html).

How could I solve this issue and succesfully connect to my instance of cyrus-imapd and using cyradm?

Comment: +1 for fighting with "generic failure" errors :)

Answer (score 2):

The command `passwd cyrus` does not set the password for the cyrus user; unless you've setup sasl to use the local passwd file.

What is your cyrus config file?  Specifically how have you configured sasl?  The link you have mentioned sasldb.  If you using sasldb, you should use saslpasswd2 to set the cyrus user password.

Comment: How do you configure cyrus to use the local password file?